# Aren't pointers supposed to point to nullptr when an array ends?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why does this code not work?, I used the function from "A Tour of C++" and it tells me that pointers point to nullptr when an array ends briefly explained. I tried to implement it and it doesn't show anything. Thanks in advance.

````
#include <iostream>

int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p) 
    {
        if (*p == x){++count;}
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}
 
int main()
{
    char my_string[] {"hello world"};
    char* my_string_ptr {my_string};

    std::cout << "There are " << count_x(my_string_ptr,'a') << " a in the string\n";

    return 0;

}```
````

Comment: String literals like `"hello world"` are char arrays that contain an implicit null terminator. The string literal `"ab"` is the array `const char c[] = {'a', 'b', '\0'};`. But this is unique to string literals. Arrays, in general, don't necessarily end with a null value

Comment: It doesn't show anything because it takes a long time for the pointer to wrap around to zero.  Your program will almost certainly crash before that happens.

Comment: Remember to accept one of the answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, pointer at the end of an array are not null. You probably want:

```
while (*p)
```

which is the same as

```
while (*p != '\0')
```

and

```
while (*p != 0)
```

which are testing for the null character.

Comment: Yup.  Null *character*, not null *pointer*.  Big difference.

Answer (score 4):

`p` stores an address value in the computer memory which is deferenced by astricks (`*`) like `*p`.
In your code,

```
p++;
```

is incrementing the current address to which the p is pointing currently. When you reach the end of the string (at the last null character), `p` will be the address of the null character not the null itself, so

```
while(p)
```

will be true and following `p++` will increment it to next memory location (which technically does not belong to the allocated string), and hence `p` will return non-zero address this while loop will keep on running and you will get a segmentation fault.

As the jeffrey has mentioned in his answer too, use `*p` to test the while condition so when p reaches the null, it can derefer it.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code crashed (or caused segmentation fault). The reason is that in the **while** loop, you did not correctly specify the condition to exit this **while** loop. Therefore, the **while** loop will continue to go past **the end of the string**, which causes segmentation fault (i.e, your app will crash).

One correct way to exit the **while** loop is to compare each character of  the string to see if that character equals the **end of string character** that is **'\0'**.

When you encounter this **end of string character** that is **'\0'**,  you should exit the **while** loop.

I have fixed one line of your code, and your function is now working fine as shown below:

```
int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
    int count = 0;
    
    while (*p != '\0')   // I fixed your code here
    {
        if (*p == x){++count;}
        p++;
     
    }
    return count;
}
```

Again, please note that the code above runs well, and produces the correct result as I have verified it. Please let me know if you run into any issue. Cheers.